# inputType=password, cannot be delete

Tags: android

I've made the same addTextChangedListener for EditText of Username and EditText of Password. I want risist user to input more when its length reach the limit character numbers. So I try to warn user by toast, and delete the new character they input. Here is the code`

```
 ETcreateusername.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(ETcreateusername.getText().length()>15){
                ETcreateusername.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(
                        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
                showToast();
            }
        }
        private void showToast() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_username,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toast_root));
            Toast toast= new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP , 0, 800);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

It can work perfectly, for EditText of Username. But whenever I input too many characters in EditText of Password, the app just go` crashed, simply because its inputType is password. Can anyone tell me why, and how can I solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Crash means there would be crash logs. Please post that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the best implementation for what you're trying to do. Maybe if you add some sort of hint saying what's the minimum and maximum characters and in your xml you can set the edit text max lentgh, like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_user"
                maxLenght="15" // This line
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/login_hint_document"
                android:inputType="number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are messing up the logic that is used to hide password characters. You should try to move your logic to the `beforeTextChanged` method. That feels kinda safer